# find the place where the variable in a dataframe changes its value

Tags: r

I have a lot of data frames in R which look like that:

```
A   B
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   1
5   1
6   1
```

So between 3 and 4 the B changes value from 0 to 1. What is the most `R` way of returning the value of `A` where `B` changes value?

In the data `B` changes the value only once, and `A` is sorted (from 1 to n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible way. Use `diff` to get the values where column `b` changes but be carefull, the first value of `b`, by definition of change, hasn't changed. (The problem is that `diff` returns a vector with one less element.)

```
inx <- c(FALSE, diff(data$b) != 0)
data[inx, ]
#  a b
#4 4 1
```

After seeing the OP's comment to another post, the following code shows that this method can also solve the issue when `b` starts with any value,not just zero.

```
data2 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),b=c(1,1,1,0,0,0))
inx <- c(FALSE, diff(data2$b) != 0)
data2[inx, ]
#  a b
#4 4 0
```

Comment: as an extra bonus, it also works if the variable changes value more than once. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As OP mentioned,

> In the data B changes the value only once

We can use `cumsum` with `duplicated` and `which.max`

```
which.max(cumsum(!duplicated(df$B)))
#[1] 4
```

If the value changes multiple times, this will give the index for last change instead.

If we need to subset the row, then we can do

```
df[which.max(cumsum(!duplicated(df$B))), ]

#  A B
#4 4 1
```

To break it down further, for better understanding

```
!duplicated(df$B)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

cumsum(!duplicated(df$B))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2

which.max(cumsum(!duplicated(df$B)))
#[1] 4
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to identify a change in a sequence, one may use `diff`, like in the following code:

```
my_df <- data.frame(A = 1:6, B = c(0,0,0,1,1,1))
which(diff(my_df$B)==1)+1
[1] 4
```